# How to get access to Vue.prototype in asyncData?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In plugin, I add new property to Vue prototype.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$DateTime', { value: DateTime });
```

I want to use it in asyncData, how to get access?

```js
async asyncData(context) {
  context.store.commit('calendar/setSelectDate', $DateTime.now());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `defineProperty` is the way to go here. You could maybe inspect the Vue instance itself and see if there is some `$DateTime` on it, if it is, a `context.$DateTime` should do the trick.

If it's not working with `context.$DateTime`, maybe try it when your component is mounted in a regular `this.$DateTime` on a button click, for debugging purposes.

---

Using regular [Nuxt plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins) or even [`inject`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context) is a more clean and Vue-y way of doing things.

```js
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('DateTime', DateTime)
}
```

then

```js
async asyncData({ store, $DateTime }) {
  store.commit('calendar/setSelectDate', $DateTime.now())
}
```

or from components/pages

```js
this.$DateTime.now()
```

Speaking of Vue, you don't want to use [vue-luxon](https://github.com/casbloem/vue-luxon). Looks like a simple and quick way of using the library. Is it because it is not mantained for already 7 months or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
async asyncData(context) {
  context.store.commit('calendar/setSelectDate', Vue.prototype.$DateTime.now());
}
```